# How to display all datetime on website in user's GMT locale?

Tags: php, gmt

I store all datetime values as unix timestamp. Registered users can set personal GMT locale in their profile. What should I do to display all datetime on website in user's GMT locale?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "user's GMT locale". You must be referring to the user's [timezone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/timezone).

You can convert unix timestamps to dates in the user timezone this way:

```
$timestamp = ...;
$tz = new DateTimezone("Europe/Lisbon"); //substitute by the user's timezone
$d = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
$d->setTimezone($d);
echo $d->format(DateTime::RFC822);
```

If you only have a GMT offset, you can use:

```
$tz = new DateTimezone("Etc/GMT-12");
```

Note, however, that if you use GMT offsets, you will have to change them when the users enter or leave daylight saving time.

Answer (score -1):

With PHP:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

With MySQL:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME()
```

Comment: In the user locale, not in the server's.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I see now Artefacto answered the question. I add just the List of Supported Timezones http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php